# Is the time complexity the same in finding target value in a 2D matrix with these 2 approaches?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

The [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix/description/) calls for searching for a target value in a 2D matrix. Both approaches use binary search.

**My approach:**

Consider the matrix as a single array where of length `rows x columns`, then use integer division and modulus to get the `row` and `column` indices in the binary search. The time complexity for this is `O(log [rows x colums])`

```
# Binary search on rows and then on columns
# Time : O(log nm) # binary search on total numbers of cells
# Space : O(1) # same number of pointers (left, right, mid) regardless of size of matrix
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def searchMatrix(self, matrix: List[List[int]], target: int) -> bool:
        ROWS = len(matrix)
        COLUMNS = len(matrix[0])

        left = 0
        right = ROWS * COLUMNS - 1 


        # run regular binary search as if dealing with just an array
        while left <= right: # <= handles case when left, right are the same and value not considered before
            mid = left + ( (right - left) // 2 )
            row = mid // COLUMNS
            col = mid %  COLUMNS # has to be COLUMNS and not ROWS. 
            # Try [[1,1]] with ROWS, will get index-out-of-range error

            # print(f"left = {left} right = {right} mid = {mid} row = {row} col = {col}")
            if target < matrix[row][col]:
                right = mid - 1
            elif target > matrix[row][col]:
                left = mid + 1
            else:
                return True

        # not found
        return False
```

**Neetcode's approach:**

I then bumped into [neetcode's solution video](https://youtu.be/Ber2pi2C0j0), where he eliminates `rows` and then focuses on just the `row` that may contain the target. Because of the elimination of the rows and then subsequent searching of the columns of the possible row, the time complexity is `O( log[rows] + O[columns] )`.

```
# Binary search on rows and then on columns
# Time : O(log n + log m) # binary search on rows then on columns
# Space : O(1) # same number of pointers (top, bottom, row, left, right) regardless of size of matrix
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def searchMatrix(self, matrix: List[List[int]], target: int) -> bool:
        ROWS = len(matrix)
        COLUMNS = len(matrix[0])

        top = 0
        bottom = ROWS - 1

        while top <= bottom:
            row = top + ((bottom-top)//2)

            if target < matrix[row][0]:
                bottom = row - 1
            elif target > matrix[row][-1]:
                top = row + 1
            else:
                # break so you can retain row value and check within the row
                break 

        # ambiguous here: could have ended here because 
        # of the break in the while loop or the while 
        # condition failed so check
        if top > bottom:
            return False

        # check within the row. 2nd binary search
        left = 0
        right = COLUMNS - 1
        
        while left <= right:
            # avoid overflow in other languages
            mid = left + ((right - left) // 2)

            if target < matrix[row][mid]:
                right = mid - 1
            elif target > matrix[row][mid]:
                left = mid + 1
            else:
                return True
        
        return False
```

In trying to figure out what was optimal in big-O notation, it occurred to me that they might be the same because `log(xy) = log(x) + log(y)` in math. Are they essentially the same?

Comment: Is this a yes/no question?

Comment: Is there a preference over the other if it is a yes, when it comes to programming and outside of the theoretical complexity? 

@trincot, I was looking for an answer in the form of either  "yes, this is a preferred one from computer resources perspective, ... " or "no, this is why it is wrong ..."

Comment: If the question is not about time complexity, then I guess you ask about actual running times? Couldn't you benchmark this?

Comment: It is about both really. You said yes, so I asked about the programming question. I wasn't sure if I had missed something so it was a yes/no question with an explanation if it were no. You could write an answer as you confirmed it.

Comment: If it is about time complexity, then you have answered the question already... there is nothing more to say. It if is not about time complexity you can do the benchmarking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two time complexities are equivalent.

It is an [identity of logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities) that

```
log(x*y) == log(x) + log(y)
```

so the two approaches have the same Big-O.